# Restart systemd service when new user created

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel, users, useradd

I need to restart a systemd service (running as root) every time a new user is created. I saw that some systems have a way to make an adduser hook but this isn't an option in RHEL8. What is the best (least invasive; most secure) way to do this?

Currently only thing I can think of is adding a script to /etc/profile.d but I'm not sure if there's a way to make it run scripts as root (without doing something insecure)

Comment: What's the purpose of that? Why would you need to restart a service every time a new user is created?

Comment: Yeah honestly after looking into it more I now realize that user home directories are created at first login and not user creation... But still the adduser hook exists for a reason.

Comment: I'd thought adding it to `/etc/profile.d` would restart the service when a user logs in, not when the user is created.

Comment: Correct, but that's close enough in my case. Only problem is that I don't think those scripts get run as root